# sed replace a setence

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace a the entire line in haha.txt that matches a pattern setence.

Orignal: `HAHA_IP_TYPE             = 1'b1`
After  : `HAHA_IP_TYPE             = 1'b0`

My command is:

```
sed -i '/HAHA_IP_TYPE             = 1'b1/HAHA_IP_TYPE = 1'b0' haha.txt
```

The error message it showed up are:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 34: extra characters after command
```

Is there anyone can help me understand it? It will be a great help.

Thanks
Jeffrey

Comment: You are missing an / at the end of statement. The syntax should be e.g. 's/original text/new text/'

Comment: @Raman, that's a `H` command, not an `s` command.

Comment: Taken from man page - 's/regexp/replacement/'

Answer (score 2):

Use double quote since your content has single quote:

```
sed -i "s/HAHA_IP_TYPE             = 1'b1/HAHA_IP_TYPE = 1'b0/" haha.txt
```